# Applying modified source code of Ubuntu program

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I downloaded the `wget` program from `http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/`, and installed it using `./configure; make; sudo make install`. Now, suppose I change the source code that was downloaded. What command exactly would I need to run in order for the changes to apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same three. `./configure` for configuration for current system and code, `make` to rebuild the program, and `sudo make install` to install the modified version.

Comment: Should I delete the old one first, or will it automatically replace the old one?

Comment: @MikaH.: it will overwrite the old one.

Comment: @MikaH.: Sure. Have fun editing the code, it can be the best way to learn.